# Incoming Mails are displayed as drafts

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I'm running a new Exchange 2013 Server and generally It's working fine. But since I replaced the old Exchange (2007) with the New one some users have a strange problem with incoming mails. The incoming mails are marked and handled as draft. When they open a Mail they received the Mail is displayed as a draft and can be edited but on the other hand the employees can't foreward or reply to these mails.

// I just noticed something. When a mail is received by the exchange server itself its not a problem. The mail is displayed correctly. But we all have more than one account and when outlook receives a mail and then stores it on the Exchange server the mail is displayed as draft.

Comment: Is this just in their mail clients (e.g. Outlook) or also when they use OWA?

Comment: Its also in the OWA

Comment: what kind of anti virus software are you using? I found a similar issue for users that are using ESET. Check this link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/emails-in-draft-mode-in-inbox/f2f39b0c-b5a7-4287-b94e-55bed603e74c?page=1

Comment: See edit please.....

Comment: So you are using 3rd party e.g. IMAP accounts on your Outlook, which stores that email on your exchange server?

Comment: Im using a thirdpary POP3 Account which is used in outlook and uses the exchange server inbox